# C++ How to output values of Vector of Maps

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Vector of Maps using an iterator how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253705/c-vector-of-maps-using-an-iterator-how-to)

This is a separate Qs on how to output values of a vector of Maps.

I have

```
typedef std::map<string, string> mapDB;
vector<pair<int,mapDB> > mapDB_vec;

mapDB_vec db;

//populate mapDB_colVal 1st row
mapDB_colVal["X"]="APPLE";
mapDB_colVal["Y"]="RED";
db.push_back(make_pair(some_row_id, mapDB_colVal));

//populate mapDB_colVal 2nd row
mapDB_colVal["X"]="PEAR";
mapDB_colval["Y"]="GREEN";
db.push_back(make_pair(some_other_row_id, mapDB_colVal));
```

how can I output values inserted into db.

like this pseudo

```
for (db.begin;db.end;)
{ 
print db[i].begin; db[i].end }
```

How can I output the values stored in db . Any help will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for (mapDB_vec::iterator i = db.begin(); i != db.end(); ++i) {
   std::cout << i->first << ": " << std::endl;
   for (mapDB::iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); ++j) {
      std::cout << "  " << j->first " - " << j->second << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Nawaz: the vector contains `std::pair`s, so `(*i).first` refers to the first element of the pair.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks for the immediate correction.

Comment: I didn't noticed the pair. So deleted my post and upvoted you. :D

Comment: @Nawaz: Yup I noticed :) I missed the pair as well initially -- I think folks more commonly use the vector's index...